How to dynamically update a bar plot in Python
I have a barplot that I'd like to update dynamically using data from a dataframe.
The original plot is based on dataframe, d:
d
Position    Operation   Side    Price   Size
1   9   0   1   0.7289  -19
2   8   0   1   0.729   -427
3   7   0   1   0.7291  -267
4   6   0   1   0.7292  -18
5   5   0   1   0.7293  -16
6   4   0   1   0.7294  -16
7   3   0   1   0.7295  -429
8   2   0   1   0.7296  -23
9   1   0   1   0.7297  -31
10  0   0   0   0.7299  41
11  1   0   0   0.73    9
12  2   0   0   0.7301  10
13  3   0   0   0.7302  18
14  4   0   0   0.7303  16
15  5   0   0   0.7304  18
16  6   0   0   0.7305  429
17  7   0   0   0.7306  16
18  8   0   0   0.7307  268
19  9   0   0   0.7308  18

Which, when plotted via the below returns this:
f, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.set_color_codes('muted')

sns.barplot(data = d[d.Side==0], x = 'Size', y = 'Price', color = 'b', orient = 'h', native_scale=True)
sns.barplot(data = d[d.Side==1], x = 'Size', y = 'Price', color = 'r', orient = 'h', native_scale=True)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(.0001))
sns.despine()


I'd like to loop through a 2nd dataframe, new_d, to update the data that's plotted.
new_d
    Position    Operation   Side    Price   Size
34  0   1   0   0.7299  39
35  1   1   0   0.73    9
36  3   1   0   0.7302  18
37  0   1   1   0.7298  -8
38  0   1   1   0.7298  -9
39  0   1   1   0.7298  -8
40  0   1   1   0.7298  -9
41  0   1   1   0.7298  -14
42  0   1   1   0.7298  -9
43  0   2   1   0.0 0
44  9   0   1   0.7288  -17
45  0   1   1   0.7297  -29
46  1   1   1   0.7296  -23
47  9   2   1   0.0 0
48  0   0   1   0.7298  -3
49  1   1   1   0.7297  -31
50  0   1   1   0.7298  -10
51  0   1   0   0.7299  41
52  0   1   1   0.7298  -4
53  0   2   1   0.0 0
54  9   0   1   0.7288  -17
55  9   2   0   0.0 0
56  0   0   0   0.7298  2
57  0   1   0   0.7298  4
58  1   1   0   0.7299  39
59  0   1   0   0.7298  5

Assuming I have code/logic that will update d from the rows of new_d, how can I dynamically update my plot?
I've tried the below using FuncAnimation but think I may be missing something.
def init():
    # f, ax = plt.subplots()
    sns.set_color_codes('muted')
   
    sns.barplot(data = d[d.Side==0], x = 'Size', y = 'Price', color = 'b', orient = 'h', native_scale=True)
    s = sns.barplot(data = d[d.Side==1], x = 'Size', y = 'Price', color = 'r', orient = 'h', native_scale=True)
    
    sns.despine()
    
    return s
    
    
def update_d(row):   
    
    if row.Operation == 1:
        d.loc[((d.Position==row.Position) & (d.Side==row.Side)), 'Size'] = row.Size
            
        
    elif row.Operation == 2:
        idx = d.loc[((d.Position==row.Position) & (d.Side==row.Side))].index
        d.drop(idx, inplace=True)
        
        
    elif row.Operation == 0:
        d = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([[row.Time, row.Symbol, row.Position, row.Operation, row.Side, row.Price, row.Size]], columns=d.columns), d], ignore_index=True)
        d['Position'] = d.groupby('Side')['Price'].rank().astype('int').sub(1)        
        d.sort_values('Price', inplace=True)    

                  
    sns.barplot(data = d[d.Side==0], x = 'Size', y = 'Price', color = 'b', orient = 'h', native_scale=True)
    s = sns.barplot(data = d[d.Side==1], x = 'Size', y = 'Price', color = 'r', orient = 'h', native_scale=True)
     
    return s
 

f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(.0001))
    
ani = FuncAnimation(f, update_d, init_func=init, frames=new_d[20:].iterrows(), interval = 100)

plt.show()


Your current approach is replotting the graph in each frame which is going to do some funky things when using FuncAnimation.
Instead you will need to:

grab the actual artist objects that seaborn is making in the graph that you want to animate. You need the artists to make manual adjustments to via the update method.
You can collect all the artists using something like this:

from  matplotlib.lines import Line2D
[a for a in ax.get_children() if isinstance(a,Line2D)]


Update the actual artist objects according to your plan.

For example see the following:
# Create the figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'b-')

# Initialization function for the plot
def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 2 * np.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return ln,

# Update function to animate the plot
def update(frame):
    xdata.append(frame)
    ydata.append(np.sin(frame))
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

# Create the animation
ani = FuncAnimation(
    fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 128),
    init_func=init, blit=False
)

plt.show()

In this example the update function is setting the data in the Line2D artist that comes from ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'b-').
Notes:

I suspect for what you are intending to do you will need to collect each artist (maybe in a dictionary/list) and make sure the ordering is correct to update the artists as described by newDf. Matching these may be kind of silly. You could use [a.get_ydata() for a in ax.get_children() if hasattr(a,'get_ydata')] to get an idea of where each artist is and that ensure that order matches what you expect with your df.iterrows function.

The updates that you want will need various calls to the artist object depending on what you want. I leave this to you as it's a bit unclear what animations you want from the question. But deleting artists, setting data in artists, and setting the position will likely be included in what you need.


At a high level this is a matplotlib concept called blitting which you can read more about here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/animations/blitting.html

Thanks, bud...prob more digging to do, but this is helpful to start.  Appreciate it!
